# How can I express this collection of attributes

Tags: grammar

There's an exercise in which I shall write short sentences about the appearance of a few children displayed in small pictures. 
I wondered how a sentence expressing the following must be constructed:

"That girl with the beautiful, short dress and the long hair."

Here I have two entities in the appearance of this girl which I want to describe. They both have to be put into nominal phrases. 
Therefore, I think it would be something along these lines:

"あの長い髪の

(?)

綺麗で短い身なりの

女の子です。"

However, as indicated by the questionmark, I wonder how these two nominal phrases shall be connected. Is there another connective particle or the like necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That girl with the beautiful, short dress and the long hair.

At first, the given phrase is a noun phrase, not a sentence because it has not a verb, so the interpretation for the phrase in Japanese must end with noun or "女の子 *girl*" not "です".

that girl with the beautiful, short dress and the long hair
= that girl with (the beautiful and short dress + the long hair)
= that girl with the beautiful and short dress + that girl with the long hair
= あの綺麗な短いドレスを着た女の子 + あの長い髪の女の子
= あの綺麗な短いドレスを着た(?)長い髪の女の子

Of course あの綺麗な短いドレス**の**女の子 is also good instead of あの綺麗な短いドレスを着た女の子.

After filling in the blank indicated by the question mark, possible answers are like:
A: あの綺麗な短いドレスを着た、そして、長い髪の女の子
B: あの綺麗な短いドレスを**着た**長い髪の女の子 (or あの綺麗な短いドレス**の**長い髪の女の子)

As for the part where the question mark is placed, そして for *and* is good like phrase A, but we usually connect the two nominal phrases like phrase B without using any connective particle or the like.

And, if we read phrase B or speak it aloud as a whole, we usually **pause a moment** just after the first phrase with "ドレスを着た or ドレスの" in order to show that the whole phrase is made up of two nominal phrases.